# gig-lot, I can't seem to change my Legend name and labels for my graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to do a scatter graph and I've been trying to change the name of my legend name and labels. However it doesn't seem to work for me.
Here is my data :

[image]

Here is my attempt to try to change the label and title name of the legend. But it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

I've also tried to change the variables name on the data frame but I get an error.

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: will do, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that if you use the `color` option in `aes()` you should use `scale_color_*()` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(followers_melt_df,
       aes(x=friend,y=total_tweets,col=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Company",
                       labels=c("Nike","Tesla"))
```

Other way to change the title in legend can be `labs(color="Company")`. And next time follow the smart **@r2evans**.

Comment: Thanks so much, This worked!! Also on my third photo, any idea why it wouldn't let me change the names of the values on my variable column?

Comment: @Q.T.π Always a pleasure!

Comment: @Q.T.π Add `$variable` before first `[`